# How to display sql data in text box

Tags: c#

My SQL database consist of a column id which contains number 1 to 30. I want to display the number 1 to 30 in a text box each time a button is pressed. However my code displays only first row that is 1. I have tried following code:

```
SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SUMIT;Initial Catalog=Project;Integrated Security=True");
SqlCommand Comm1 = new SqlCommand("Select * from id", Conn);
Conn.Open();
SqlDataReader DR1 = Comm1.ExecuteReader();

if (DR1.Read())
{
    textBox3.Text = DR1.GetValue(0).ToString();

}
Conn.Close();
```

Comment: And what UI toolkit are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is causing the issue -

```
textBox3.Text = DR1.GetValue(0).ToString();
```

here the value of `textBox3` is getting overriden with every loop.

Instead you should append the `textBox3` value with each iteration -

```
textBox3.Text = textBox3.Text + DR1.GetValue(0).ToString();
```

*Use `while` loop instead of `if`*

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop

```
While (DR1.read())
{
textBox3.Text += DR1.GetValue(0).ToString();
}
```